# Returning multiple cursors to template

Tags: meteor

I have a template helper called `notifications` and I want to return 3 collection cursors to my template, so that I can view all

Template

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu notification">
    {{#if notificationCount}}
        {{#each notifications}}
            {{> notification}}
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        <li><span>No Notifications</span></li>
    {{/if}}
</ul>
```

Helper

```
notifications: function() {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
        var accepted = Notifications.find({ origin: Meteor.user().username, status: 'ACCEPTED' });
        var denied = Notifications.find({ rival: Meteor.user().username, status: 'DENIED' });
        var confirmed = Notifications.find({ rival: Meteor.user().username, status: 'CONFIRMED' });
        return accepted, denied, confirmed;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal answer to your question is to run `fetch` on all of the cursors and concatenate them into a single array.

```js
return accepted.fetch().concat(denied.fetch(), confirmed.fetch());
```

Because all of your documents come from a single collection, you can alternatively use a more sophisticated query. Give this a try:

```js
var username = Meteor.user().username;
return Notifications.find({
  $or: [
    {
      origin: username,
      status: 'ACCEPTED'
    }, {
      rival: username,
      status: {$in: ['DENIED', 'CONFIRMED']}
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks David! I really like that query. I don't know why I didn't think to do that!